# SSIS package creates .csv file, adds columns but no rows

Tags: csv, visual-studio-2015, ssis

So I can test the connection in OLE DB Source and it connects.

I can Preview the stored procedure in the OLE DB Source Editor.

The Error Output window in OLE DB Source Editor has Error and Truncation set to "Fail Component" (I tried the other choices too).

The .csv file is created and adds the column header names.

But there are no rows of data.

EDIT. Someone mentioned I should include Stored Procedure. It is very simple for testing purposes. I did replace "SELECT * FROM tblReport" with 
"SELECT RPT_ID, RPT_Name, RPT_Description, RPT_DBTimestamp, RPT_Active, RPT_INSDate, RPT_Note FROM tblReport". I removed all columns I wasn't using.

Here is the new text from my Output window when I run in debug mode. It still is the same and the output columns are the ones I am expecting to see in the Excel file, but Output Window says "not subsequently used" for all of them.

```
SSIS package "C:\Mail_Merge\ExportToExcel_2\Package.dtsx" starting.
Information: 0x4004300A at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
Warning: 0x80208385 at Data Flow Task, OLE DB Source [23]: No rows will be sent to error output(s). Configure error or truncation dispositions to redirect rows to the error output(s), or delete data flow transformations or destinations that are attached to the error output(s).
Information: 0x4004300A at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
Warning: 0x80208385 at Data Flow Task, OLE DB Source [23]: No rows will be sent to error output(s). Configure error or truncation dispositions to redirect rows to the error output(s), or delete data flow transformations or destinations that are attached to the error output(s).
Warning: 0x80047076 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: The output column "RPT_ID" (35) on output "OLE DB Source Output" (34) and component "OLE DB Source" (23) is not subsequently used in the Data Flow task. Removing this unused output column can increase Data Flow task performance.
Warning: 0x80047076 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: The output column "RPT_Name" (36) on output "OLE DB Source Output" (34) and component "OLE DB Source" (23) is not subsequently used in the Data Flow task. Removing this unused output column can increase Data Flow task performance.
Warning: 0x80047076 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: The output column "RPT_Description" (37) on output "OLE DB Source Output" (34) and component "OLE DB Source" (23) is not subsequently used in the Data Flow task. Removing this unused output column can increase Data Flow task performance.
Warning: 0x80047076 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: The output column "RPT_DBTimestamp" (38) on output "OLE DB Source Output" (34) and component "OLE DB Source" (23) is not subsequently used in the Data Flow task. Removing this unused output column can increase Data Flow task performance.
Warning: 0x80047076 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: The output column "RPT_Active" (39) on output "OLE DB Source Output" (34) and component "OLE DB Source" (23) is not subsequently used in the Data Flow task. Removing this unused output column can increase Data Flow task performance.
Warning: 0x80047076 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: The output column "RPT_INSDate" (40) on output "OLE DB Source Output" (34) and component "OLE DB Source" (23) is not subsequently used in the Data Flow task. Removing this unused output column can increase Data Flow task performance.
Warning: 0x80047076 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: The output column "RPT_Note" (41) on output "OLE DB Source Output" (34) and component "OLE DB Source" (23) is not subsequently used in the Data Flow task. Removing this unused output column can increase Data Flow task performance.
Information: 0x40043006 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Prepare for Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x40043007 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Pre-Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x402090DC at Data Flow Task, Flat File Destination [2]: The processing of file "C:\SSIS\testSSIS.csv" has started.
Information: 0x4004300C at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x40043008 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Post Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x402090DD at Data Flow Task, Flat File Destination [2]: The processing of file "C:\SSIS\testSSIS.csv" has ended.
Information: 0x4004300B at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: "Flat File Destination" wrote 0 rows.
Information: 0x40043009 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Cleanup phase is beginning.
SSIS package "C:\Mail_Merge\ExportToExcel_2\Package.dtsx" finished: Success.
```

ANOTHER EDIT: Screen-print of Control Flow with exclamation point.
Hovering over the Exclamation Point it displays:
"No Rows will be sent to error output(s). Configure error or truncation dispositions to redirect rows."  HUH?

[image]

Comment: Posting your stored procedure helps but regardless... stored procedures can have confusing results, Make sure it always returns exactly onerecordset, it always has the same metadata, and you have `SET NOCOUNT ON;` at the top.

Comment: Going by your log.... have you mapped columns from the SP result into the CSV file? Are the columns mentioned in the log excluded on purpose?

Comment: and since Error and Truncation set to "Redirect row", you need to have those redirected rows going somewhere. I suggest in the interests of debugging that you choose 'fail component' instead as that will give an error that you can use to troubleshoot

Comment: Ok Nick. I have include my very simple stored procedure. It has SET NOCOUNT ON at the top. I have the columns mapped into the CSV file. The columns mentioned in the log are actually the ones I am using. I have changed "Redirect Row" to "fail component". But still no luck.

Comment: _The output column "RPT_ID" (35) on output "OLE DB Source Output" (34) and component "OLE DB Source" (23) is not subsequently used in the Data Flow task. Removing this unused output column can increase Data Flow task performance._ means that column RPT_ID is **not** used in your data flow at all and you haven't mapped it

Comment: The code you posted is not a stored procedure. What is the exact code you are using in the source component? is it what you posted?

Comment: Yes. One simple select query. And RPT_ID is mapped. I have no columns from the SP that aren’t mapped.

Comment: So there is no stored procedure in in this situation at all. Going by your last screenshot you have not mapped the green data flow (successful output) to anything

Comment: You should start by learning what a stored procedure is, _or_ learn how to explain your situation properly. I may sound like I'm stuck on this but you need to be able to explain your situation in order to solve it

Comment: @Nick I don't need to learn anything more about stored procedures, trust me. I said in my OP that I was using a stored procedure. For the purpose of saving space I just included the SQL in the stored procedure. It was very very simple proof of concept stored procedure hitting one table. Let's move on I know you are dying to help me. I went to bed and it is 1:18am and I woke up and realized you had solved my error when you pointed out "Going by your last screenshot you have not mapped the green data flow (successful output) to anything". That is exactly where I was stuck at.

Comment: @Nick, please make your comment "Going by your last screenshot you have not mapped the green data flow (successful output) to anything" an answer and I will accept it. Only fair and thank you very much. Now I know what the Green arrow is for and the Red Arrow. (in my defense the Green arrow is dark grey on my computer. LOL)

Comment: I’m pleased you sorted your issue

Comment: We sorted my issue. Smiley face here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the data flow leading into the target is the success data flow, not the failure data flow. It seems from your screenshot that only the failure dataflow is mapped through.

Comment: Thank you for sticking around and trying different stuff.

Answer (score 0):

A destination file, error or not, will always be created regardless of whether rows are supplied.

If you need to take logic based on rows having been sent to the destination, then you'll need to create an SSIS Variable and attach it to a Row Count transformation. After the data flow task, you'll then need to take action based on the count. Some people choose to just use a Script task to inspect the file but I find it a better practice to just record my counts as I go instead of checking after the fact.